# Next.js Having an installation fail and react.js package fail when installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Error: Several Installation fails upon Next.js installation including a package loss revealed during build

> peema@DESKTOP-6UGCO8V MINGW64 ~/Documents/alert/peeapp $ next build
> The module 'react' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it
> in 'depen dencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install
> react' The module 'react-dom' was not found. Next.js requires that you
> include it in 'd ependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run
> 'npm install react-dom' uncaughtException Error: Cannot find module
> '@next/env'

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing Next.js installation process and failure and next build failure.
An installation process that worked in a breakdown

**PRECHECK**
a)Open permissions to avoid permission restriction and fail
b)If permission is an issue, set permission to Everybody, User  etc. on your Windows or Mac
c) Check anti-virus issues(antivirus can block files)

**INSTALLATION**

1. yarn global add create-next-app- (to make it accessible and to create binary )
2. npm install -g npm@latest - (to make it ready for npm files _
3. yarn create next-app peeapp - (create project )
4. yarn global bin -(to check binary - check binary path)
5. yarn global list - (check if the project exists in global list)
6. create-next-app peeapp - (this is what creates the project)

**PATH FIXES**

1. If you have path error, put the path of the project and the bin directory in the System Environment Variables both as a Users & System
2. Check for the binary. Eg C:\Users\peema.yarn-global\bin, and you can place it in Path at the System or User Environment Variables

**PROBLEM: NEXT BUILD REACT ERROR AND INSTALLATION ERRORS FOR NEXT BUILD**
**However, there is an issue, next.js installs the project in the directory where you run the create-next-app command
(rightly so). but a problem with **'next build'** occurs

Let's take the two path
a) C:\Users\peema\Documents\alert\peeapp\node_modules
b) C:\Users\peema\node_modules*

The project was installed in peeapp folder hence the node_modules (*C:\Users\peema\Documents\alert\peeapp\node_modules*)  but (**next build** ) calls the second path (*C:\Users\peema\node_modules* )

*So packages like react, next, and others cannot be found since they are not in the second path but were installed in the first.*

**SOLUTION:**
**Copy all packages that are not in the first *node_modules* to the second so that those packages can be found.**